# How to post data of different form with same field name in same `cshtml` page to the same controller method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have many form in same `cshtml` page with same field name. I want to post the data of the specific form to the controller on the submit button of specific form. How to achieve it?

I have created jquery method as bellow,

```
 var valSettings = {
        rules: {
            CompanyName: {
                required: true,
            },
            ContactPerson: {
                required: true,
            },
            ContactNo: {
                required: true,
            },
            EmailID: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Querytype: {
                required: function (element) {
                    if ($("input[name='Querytype'] option:selected").text() == "Kindly select") {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        messages: {
            CompanyName: "Company Name field should not be blank.",
            ContactPerson: "Contact Person field should not be blank.",
            ContactNo: "Contact No field should not be blank.",
            EmailID: {
                required: "Contact No field should not be blank.",
                email: "Please specify a valid email address"
            },
            Querytype: "Query Type field should not be blank.",
        },
        submitHandler: function () {

            var data = new FormData($(this).get(0));


            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveContactDetails", "StaticPage")",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data == 1) {
                        bootbox.alert("Contact details saved succesfully!!");
                        $(this)[0].reset();
                        //var validator = $('#frmContactIndia').validate();
                        //validator.resetForm();

                    }
                    else {
                        bootbox.alert("Error in saving contact details! Please try again later!");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    $('#frmContactIndia').validate(valSettings);

    $('#frmContactBelgium').validate(valSettings);
```

my controller action method,

```
  public int SaveContactDetails(ContactUsModel _objContactUsModel)
{
   return 1;
}
```

I am getting value in `_objContactUsModel` while submit 1st form. but when i submit other form i am getting null value for each field in `_objContactUsModel`.

Html view,

```
    <form role="form" id="frmContactIndia" method="post">

        <div id="india" class="ofc-cont graytexturebg pageblock blockcontainer" data-scroll-index="1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="innerheading">India Office</div>
                <div class="ofcinfo">
                    <div class="left-addr">
                        <div class="jbbroshkttl">India - Mumbai</div>
                        <div class="addr">
                            J.B. And Brothers Pvt. Ltd.<br />
                            Tower FC-3011/12, 3rd Floor, Bharat Diamond Bourse,<br />
                            BKC, Bandra(East), Mumbai-400051
                        </div>
                        <div class="tel">Tel : +91 22 40342222 <span>|</span> Fax : +91 22 40342299</div>
                        <div class="tel">Mktg : +91 9833812803/4/5/6 <span>|</span> +91 9769223739</div>
                        <div class="email">Email : info@jbbrothers.com</div>
                        <div class="email">Skype : jbmarketingteam</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-addr">
                        <div class="jbbroshkttl">India - Surat</div>
                        <div class="addr">
                            J.B. And Brothers Pvt. Ltd.<br />
                            Patel Wadi-3, Near Shivanjali Row House, Near Natraj Cinema,<br />
                            Laldarwaja, Surat-395 004.
                        </div>
                        <div class="tel">Tel : +91 261 260 7777 <span>|</span> Fax : +91 261 260 7888</div>
                        <div class="email">Email : info@jbbrothers.com</div>
                        <div class="email">Skype : jbmarketingteam</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="assicont">
                    <div class="assi-heading">
                        <div class="jbbroshkttl">For more assistance</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="assi-form">
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ContactType" value="India - Mumbai" />
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company name" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="ContactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="ContactNo" placeholder="Contact No." class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="EmailID" placeholder="Email ID" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <select name="Querytype" class="assiformselectflidblk">
                                    <option>Kindly select</option>
                                    <option>Website</option>
                                    <option>Sales query</option>
                                    <option>Technical Assistant</option>
                                    <option>Export / Shipment</option>
                                    <option>Accounting</option>
                                    <option>Senior management</option>
                                    <option>Director</option>
                                    <option>Human Resource</option>
                                    <option>Other</option>
                                </select>
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap assitextareawrap">
                                <textarea name="queryDetail" placeholder="Query" class="assiformtextareablk"></textarea>
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="ibvm">
                                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit now" class="green-btn uppercase" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibvm">
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="gray-btn uppercase" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


   <form role="form" id="frmContactBelgium" method="post">

        <div id="belgium" class="bluetexturebg ofc-cont pageblock blockcontainer" data-scroll-index="2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="innerheading whitecolor">Belgium - Antwerpen</div>
                <div class="addrdetails">
                    <div class="addr">
                        Yaelstar BVBA<br />
                        30 Hoveniersstraat, Box 154, Suite # 807, 8th Floor,<br />
                        B - 2018, Antwerp, Belgium.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="addrdetails">
                    <div class="tel">Tel : +32 3231 0022 <span>|</span> Fax : +32 3231 5623</div>
                    <div class="tel">Mktg : +32 477 678020</div>
                </div>
                <div class="addrdetails">
                    <div class="email">Email : yaelstar@telenet.be</div>
                    <div class="email">Skype : riikesh</div>
                </div>

                <div class="assicont">
                    <div class="assi-heading">
                        <div class="jbbroshkttl">For more assistance</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="assi-form">
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ContactType" value="Belgium - Antwerpen" />
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company name" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="ContactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="ContactNo" placeholder="Contact No." class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <input type="text" name="EmailID" placeholder="Email ID" class="assiformfildblk" />
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap">
                                <select name="Querytype" class="assiformselectflidblk">
                                    <option>Kindly select</option>
                                    <option>Website</option>
                                    <option>Sales query</option>
                                    <option>Technical Assistant</option>
                                    <option>Export / Shipment</option>
                                    <option>Accounting</option>
                                    <option>Senior management</option>
                                    <option>Director</option>
                                    <option>Human Resource</option>
                                    <option>Other</option>
                                </select>
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="assiformflidwrap assitextareawrap">
                                <textarea name="queryDetail" placeholder="Query" class="assiformtextareablk"></textarea>
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="assirow">
                            <div class="ibvm">
                                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit now" class="green-btn uppercase" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibvm">
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="gray-btn uppercase" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You have not shown your view and its forms. And why do you have form controls with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't refer to the form element inside [`submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#submithandler). To get the current `form`, you can use the `form` argument.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
   var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveContactDetails", "StaticPage")",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data == 1) {
                bootbox.alert("Contact details saved succesfully!!");
                form.reset(); // you need to change this as well
            }
            else {
                bootbox.alert("Error in saving contact details! Please try again later!");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

[If you use `HTML Helpers` to create your form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation), then you don't need to handle all these validations manually. You just have to add validation attributes like `Required` to the properties.